# cant open previously logged-in amazon sites, cant upload new key to gitlab, cant join slack calls or upload files

Tags: linux, git, networking, tcp, udp

All my problems look related.

1. Cant open sites like amazon.in or amazon.com, but I can open amazon.com.au. Checked both the sites in private browsing and they worked but cant login gets stuck or remains on the same page without any errors when I click on 'continue' after entering my email id.
2. Cant open zoom.us. Some how zoom.us session expired and I tried accessing it again, YES I could see the page but when I try logging in, again same problem as above the request just doesn't happen.

Conclusion: cant login from site in which I previously logged in or the session is saved.

3. None of my git remote commands work. (ex. git pull) I use a private organization gitlab instance, so I checked my keys, I deleted my existing key and tried adding new BUT after entering all the details and clicking on 'Add Key', it freezes for some time and shows this

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

4. I cant join other calls, upload photo or video in my slack workspace, but everyone else can! I tried contacting the support they had send me a test link BUT again am not able to access the test link as it required logging into slack account from browser.

So am basically dead! Some update may have caused this issue!

System details:

Hardware: Dell Latitude 3400

Wifi: Intel Cannon Point-LP (i also tried plugging in a external wifi card but no luck)

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Linux 5.10.8 kernal

Some of the things that I already tried ->

1. contact slack support team, not much of help because the problem affected whole OS!
2. restart a gazillion times
3. change ips
4. change network connection
5. change wifi card
6. update linux kernal

Everything worked till 18th Jan! and Nothing worked on 19th Jan after a 'Ubuntu-base' update, but I also dont remember if there was any other update!

Answer (score 0):

Found a issue bit similar but more about browser cookies.

Decrease MTU, to learn more about it check out this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37141528/14482966